# bootstrap form how doe I use 2 textboxes in one bootstrap column

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap horizontal form on the left the labels and on the right textboxes. For the address I would like to split the textboxes in address and adrressnumber.
    
            
                
                    Streett & nr. :

Comment: more info required.   picture of end result.  your current attempts you have tried.  what have you researched ?  results ?  links / references ?  what documentation have you read ?

Answer (score 0):

Create another `row` inside the column. Then to add two `col-xs-12` cols and they will stack on top of each other - I think that is what u r getting at...

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nesting columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting). For example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
  <form class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputName" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Name</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Name">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="inputStreet" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Address</label>
      <div class="col-sm-10">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputStreet" placeholder="Street">
          </div>
          <div class="col-xs-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputNumber" placeholder="Number">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: I always put a `row` inside the `container`. The  `row` `col` `row` `col` etc format makes sure margins and padding don't get screwed up. Just think it is good practice. Only exception seems to be special classes such as `navbar`, `page-header`, `jumbotron` etc. I realize this works here (not sure if `form-horizontal` is a special class) but as general practice highly recommend `row/col` to beginner of Bootstrap unless any need to the contrary. IMHO

Comment: @BeNice Thank you for your comment. I've found this instruction at http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal 
`Use Bootstrap's predefined grid classes to align labels and groups of form controls in a horizontal layout by adding .form-horizontal to the form (which doesn't have to be a <form>). Doing so changes .form-groups to behave as grid rows, so no need for .row.`